# Tratamento casas decimais EditText

Tags: java, android, edittext

Preciso definir uma quantidade de casas decimais para um `EditText` no Android. Para isso usei um `InputFilter` como mostro abaixo:

```
public NumeroFormatado(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) 
{
    mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero - 1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");        
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

    Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);
    if(!matcher.matches())
        return "";
    return null;
}
```

E na minha Activity eu defino:

```
editValor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editValor);
editValor.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new NumeroFormatado(10,2)});
```

Porém quando informo um valor como por exemplo `22.85` e clico no botão próximo do teclado, o campo perde as casas decimais. Se eu informo `22.80` funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastou um ajuste no `InputFilter` e a classe ficou como mostro abaixo:

```
public class NumeroFormatado implements InputFilter{    

 private int mDigitsBeforeZero;
 private int mDigitsAfterZero;
 private Pattern mPattern;

 private static final int DIGITS_BEFORE_ZERO_DEFAULT = 100;
 private static final int DIGITS_AFTER_ZERO_DEFAULT = 100;

 public NumeroFormatado(Integer digitsBeforeZero, Integer digitsAfterZero) {
    this.mDigitsBeforeZero = (digitsBeforeZero != null ? digitsBeforeZero : DIGITS_BEFORE_ZERO_DEFAULT);
    this.mDigitsAfterZero = (digitsAfterZero != null ? digitsAfterZero : DIGITS_AFTER_ZERO_DEFAULT);
    mPattern = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]{0," + (mDigitsBeforeZero) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (mDigitsAfterZero)
            + "})?)||(\\.)?");
}

 @Override
 public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

    String replacement = source.subSequence(start, end).toString();
    String newVal = dest.subSequence(0, dstart).toString() + replacement
            + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length()).toString();
    Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(newVal);
    if (matcher.matches())
        return null;

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(source))
        return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
    else
        return "";
 }
}
```

Na `Activity` continua a mesma chamada:

```
editValor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editValor);
editValor.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new NumeroFormatado(10,2)});
```

Comment: Obrigado ai pela sua resposta. Era exatamente o que eu estava procurando!